# Vuejs updating the child component when updating parent data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a component that displays a detailed description of a person, this component has a table displaying his technique, I need to update (redraw) this table when I press the button

```html
<template>
  <div class="animated fadeIn">
    <b-row>
      <b-col xs="12" lg="12">
        <b-card>
          <div slot="header">
            Person:
            <strong>Name</strong>
            <b-button @click="Update"></b-button>
          </div>
          <b-row>
            <TransactionsTable ref="TransactionsTable"/>
            </b-row>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TransactionsTable from "./TransactionsTable.vue";

export default {
 components: {    
    TransactionsTable
 },
  methods: {
    Update() {
      this.$refs.TransactionsTable.$forceUpdate();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: you have to add the `components` object in your `export default` declaration. So try `components: {transactionsTable: TransactionsTable}` in your `export default`, then change template syntax to `<transactions-table ref="TransactionsTable"></transactions-table>`

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman - `components: { TransactionsTable }` would probably be more succinct and follows naming conventions for components

Comment: forgot to copy to the example, it was - does not work like that

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `TransactionsTable` seems to manage it's own state, instead of calling `.$forceUpdate()`, add a method to `TransactionsTable`.  Call that from the parent, and then mutate the state within the `TransactionsTable` method.

You should really never need to call $forceUpdate if you wire things up correctly.

Comment: good idea, is there an example?

Comment: We would need to see some code from `TransactionsTable` to make it applicable to your use case.  Just remember any methods you add to the `methods:{}` block can be called from the parent.  If that method updates fields in the `data` block, they will refresh automatically.

Comment: I solved the problem according to your suggestion using this.$emit and this.$on